# Insert Image path from json into datatable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

Good afternoon, I am trying to insert an image into my datatable. The value is coming from a json file. There are 5 images coming back from PictometryImages. I am trying to render the first image.

Here is a snippet from my json for Pictometry Images

```
                "PictometryImages": [
                    {
                        "Pin": "14738849560000",
                        "ImageName": "14738849560000_east.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "Pin": "14738849560000",
                        "ImageName": "14738849560000_west.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "Pin": "14738849560000",
                        "ImageName": "14738849560000_north.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "Pin": "14738849560000",
                        "ImageName": "14738849560000_south.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "Pin": "14738849560000",
                        "ImageName": "14738849560000_down.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "PIN": "14738858340000",
                "ClassCode": "106",
                "ClassCdDesc": "106 Homeowners Association",
                "NeighNumber": 9996001,
                "NeighName": "Homeowners Assoc",
                "SitusStreet": "3788 River Oak Cir",
```

Here is the jquery

```
  $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('#example').dataTable({
                responsive: true, 
                "ajax": "/properties.json", 
                "columns": [{ "data": "PictometryImages" }, { "data": "PIN" }, { "data": "NeighName" }, { "data": "SitusStreet" }], 
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, data, iDisplayIndex ) { 
                    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<img src="/_images/' + data.PictometryImages[0].ImageName[0] + '"/>');
                    return nRow;
                },
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, data, iDisplayIndex ) {
                    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="/_pages/details.html?gpin=' + data.PIN + '">' + data.PIN + '</a>'); 
                    return nRow;
                }, 
                "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }]
            });
        }
    );
```

Instead of rendering an image, it renders this:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to this.

Thank you,

Comment: Woudln't `data.PictometryImages[0].ImageName[0]` be just `"1"`? I would have removed the last `[0]`.

Comment: Keeping the [0] or removing it still gives me the five objects that are a part of pictometry images. I want to render the first image from PictometryImages. data.PictometryImages[0].ImageName isn't working either.

Comment: So apparently you can't have two fnRowCallback functions. I ended up adding the pictometry image code to the second fnRowCallback function and it works. Code is below:

Comment: "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, data, iDisplayIndex ) {
                       /$('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<img src="/_images/' + data.PictometryImages[0].ImageName + '"/>');
                        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="/_pages/details.html?gpin=' + data.PIN + '">' + data.PIN + '</a>'); 
                        return nRow;
                    },

Comment: Yeah actually it is a JavaScript object property: You cannot have two fields with the same name in a JSON.